# Date sorting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column which stores date in format of `mm/dd/yyyy`.

When I retrieve value from this table order by date then it returns the dates in descending order of month but ascending order of day.

e.g.

```
date
=========
09/20/2018
09/21/2018
09/22/2018
10/15/2018
10/16/2018
08/07/2018
08/06/2018

select * from table order by date;
```

Current result:

```
10/15/2018
10/16/2018
09/20/2018
09/21/2018
09/22/2018
08/06/2018
08/07/2018
```

Expected result:

```
10/16/2018
10/15/2018
09/22/2018
09/21/2018
09/20/2018
08/07/2018
08/06/2018
```

Comment: What is the **datatype** of this column??

Comment: nvarchar is the datatype

Comment: Since those are **strings**- they are absolutely correctly sorted. If you want to have date&time - why aren't you storing them as `DATETIME2(n)` or `DATE` ????? If you did, *then* you could sort them as dates .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can need to convert your column to date before sorting

```
select * from table order by CONVERT(datetime, date) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

use order by desc and use cast so whatever your data type is - it will convert it into date and then order by desc

```
select * from table order by cast([date] as date) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use `DESC` after `ORDER BY` like this `select * from table order by date DESC`